# How do I cast on an update? The data field is set to vchar(4) and I would like to cast it as an int

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

This is what I have come up with so far but I am getting a syntax error

```
   update t_Provider set(CAST(f_Postnr as int)) = '66886' where f_Name= 'Test1'
```

Comment: Don't you want to cast the character-type value '66886' to an int? The left part of the `SET somecolumn = somevalue` part is supposed to be a column name.

Comment: The problem is I can't put more than four character into the data field so I am trying to cast f_Postnr to an int or even nvarchar(10) would be fine.

Comment: Use `ALTER TABLE` and modify the column to `nvarchar(11)` or - even better - to `int`, if you are storing only integers.

Comment: dont I have to drop the table to that?

Answer (score 0):

By your question, I assume column `f_Postnr` is a `NVARCHAR(4)`.

You cannot insert data into this column with a greater character length then 4.

Any solution would require you to edit the column length.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the syntax for an update in [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)..

The left hand side of the assignment has to be a known memory location (variable or column/field).  What you are doing is trying to set and expression (unknown location) to a constant and filter by a where clause.

Use this code to do what you want.

```
-- Code from user
update t_Provider 
set f_Postnr = 66886 
where f_Name= 'Test1'
```

Why not pass the constant in the update without stating it as a string ''?  That's what the above snippet does.  This assumes f_Postnr is a INT which can easily handle a 66K number (domain constraint).

If you use '66886', SQL Server will implicit cast the string to an integer if there are no errors.

Here is a huge chart for [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) on implicit casting matrix.

I hope this helps with your future TSQL endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

What about using...

```
UPDATE t_Provider
SET f_Postnr = CAST('66886' AS INT)
WHERE f_Name = 'Test1'
```

Comment: Although my solution should technically do the job you require, I will point out that using CASTs on UPDATEs upon very large tables is not usually a good idea. Maybe there is some clever indexing that can negate this potential bottleneck but it may be a good idea to CAST that '66886' in one step and then perform the UPDATE on t_Provider after that, in a separate step.